# "Supplied storage credentials were not accepted by the server" error when trying to bootstrap juju

Tags: juju, maas

This is the error while bootstrap

```
clusteruser@cluster:~$ juju bootstrap
2012-08-04 03:05:23,536 INFO Bootstrapping environment 'maas' (origin: ppa type: maas)...
2012-08-04 03:05:23,694 ERROR Bootstrap aborted because file storage is not writable: The supplied storage credentials were not accepted by the server
```

I've configured the environment . What should I do ?

Comment: How does you environment file looks like?

Comment: The environment file i created was exactly the way it was in installation , i am doing through vmware .. Am i missing something ?

Comment: @Ahsan Can you please post it so we can review it.

Answer (score 1):

There's two possible reasons why you are getting this response.

1. Did you follow the instructions at https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ServerTeam/MAAS/Juju to set up the API key in the environments file?
2. The Django settings file on the MAAS server has a setting called "MEDIA_ROOT".  It needs to be set to a directory that is writable by the user that is running the MAAS server.

Comment: I tried to address both reasons without luck. I generated MAAS API keys and inserted into the environments file with and without the ${} but with no luck. I tracked down the MEDIA_ROOT and set it to a  folder in the cobbler website. The user that is running the MAAS server (created with createadminuser) is root. What am I doing wrong?